# PHP - Weird behaviour with JSON decoded variable

Tags: php, json, curl, slim

I have a rather strange behavior in my app and run out of ideas. I'm trying to create a small REST API using Slim. I use cURL to call the page and the requests are in JSON format. Slim reads the body and decodes using `json_decode(value, true)` to return an Array. Please find the post function:

```
$app->post('/users', function () use ($app, $log)
{
   $body = $app->request()->getBody();
   echo $body['username']; // Will throw Illegal string offset 'username'

   if (isset($body["username"]) && isset($body["password"]))
   {
      echo $body['username']; // Will work
   }
   else
   {
      throw new \API\Exception\ValidationException("Invalid arguments"); // Is thrown all the time
   }
});
```

**Problem 1**:
Even though `$body` is returned as array from `json_decode`, accessing a member will throw an `Illegal string offset` error and stop the code.

```
 var_dump($body); // array(2) { ["username"]=> string(8) "testuser"    ["password"]=> string(8) "testpass" }
 echo is_array($body); // 1
 echo $body['username']; // Illegal string offset 'username'
 echo array_key_exists('username', $body); // Illegal string offset 'username'
```

The solution I found is placing `isset($body[key])` and the code will go on like nothing happens. Let's say this is a fix, but one I do not like. I would like to understand why this happens. However it still leads me to problem 2.

**Problem 2**:
If I try to place an exception outside the `isset` block, it will throw it every time (even if the parameter has a value or not).

This makes no sense to me and I tried everything that comes to mind. I have also a `GET` `/users/:username` where I also validate the username using an Exception and all works just fine. It only happens after reading parameters from a `POST` encoded in JSON.

I have tested both under IIS(servers are on Windows) and Apache, and also PHP 5.5 and 5.6 (both x64).

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Also the cURL call:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "pemPath"); //Intentionally deleted the CAinfo path
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myauth"); //Intentionally deleted credentials
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/api/v1/users");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST", "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"));
$postArr = array("username" => "testuser", "password" => "testpass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: `&` should be `&&` ?

Comment: You can give multiple arguments to `isset()` it will test them all.

Comment: Does `is_array($body)` really return `Array` rather than `true`?

Comment: I suspect you have a typo somewhere, so you're using a different variable when you try to access the `username` element.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Sorry I had a typo here and not in the code (with &&). It's not from that unfortunately. As I said it's strange. If I replace the exception with a simple echo the code works just fine in both cases (exists or not).

Comment: Have you tried typecasting to array before accessing the array, something like: `(array) $body`?

Comment: Yes and it solves problem 1. The first echo will not give "Illegal string.." anymore, yet the exception in the IF statement is still thrown even though both "username" and "password" are keys of the array, thus my frustrations.

Comment: More strangely if I just put `(array) $body` and pass the array to another function it will see any key as `NULL` unless I also typecast the key value (Example: `(string) $arr["username"]`. So far only placing the `isset` has proven successful in continuing the logic of the code without further specific changes.

Comment: Hey @SomeOtherGuy, have you found a solution for this issue? If so, please add an answer to your question explaining what you did. Just checking: you're using the `ContentTypes` middleware, right?

Comment: That `var_dump` output look odd: I suspect the key is: `["testuser"]` not "testuser". Yes, I know it looks odd. i.e. the '[' were not added by var_dump but are actually part of the string. `echo key($array);` to see it. I would check the returned JSON string. It is perfectly valid as a key in PHP but it is confusing.